# firebase-messaging-sw.js won't allow import statement. How to use firebase onBackgroundMessage in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase Messaging Service in my Angular project.

Firebase onMessage is working correctly when app is in focus but I'm unable to figure out how to use onBackgroundMessage and show a system notification to users.

I followed this [Firebase Messaging Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) but unable to import onBackgroundMessage  from "firebase/messaging/sw" like in the guide.

If I use import statement it says import statement can not be used outside a module.

Currently My firbase-messaging-sw.js looks like this.

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");
console.log('123asd123ascd')
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAyGD0QIxpGieOtvEvFBzJMO5l5WnQxwEw",
  authDomain: "notifications-test-a3170.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "notifications-test-a3170",
  storageBucket: "notifications-test-a3170.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "301382591226",
  appId: "1:301382591226:web:7646ab699982008f35df43",
  measurementId: "G-E58TMQZWLP",
  senderId: 301382591226,
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);
```

I want my firebase-messaing-sw.js like this

```
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
import { onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const messaging = getMessaging();
onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: have you registered the service worker properly?

Comment: include the code that cuases the error, not the code you dont want to have

Comment: @PrashantSingh Service worker is in root directory firebase messaging use this file as default service worker I have checked in the browser service worker is registering

Answer (score 0):

you need to export something from the file that import the firebase services. You need to include the call to `onBackgroundMessage` somewhere anyway, otherwise it won't run. I don't know what `self` refers to though.